# Multivariable regression model cost does not decrease

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scikit-learn, regression, linear-regression

I am trying to implement a multivariable regression model with mean square error as cost function and gradient descent to optimize the parameters. Over 1000 iterations, the cost functions does not decrease. I am not sure if i am implementing the gradients correctly. Also, how can i incorporate bias into it. I know that for simple linear model, bias is the y-intercept but how can i implement it here.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets

class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.0001, n_iters=1000):
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.n_iters = n_iters
        #since we have three independent variable, we initialize three weights with zeros
        self.weights = np.array([[0.0],[0.0],[0.0]])

    def update_param(self, x_featureset, y_targets, weights):
        """
        x_featureset - (160,3)
        y_targets - (160,1)
        predictions - (160,1)
        weights - (3,1)
        """
        predictions = self.predict(x_featureset, weights)

        #extract the features
        x1 = x_featureset[:,0]
        x2 = x_featureset[:,1]
        x3 = x_featureset[:,2]

        #calculate partial derivatives
        d_w1 = -x1*(y_targets - predictions)
        d_w2 = -x2*(y_targets - predictions)
        d_w3 = -x2*(y_targets - predictions)

        #multiply derivative by learning rate and subtract from our weights
        weights[0][0] -= (self.lr*np.mean(d_w1))
        weights[1][0] -= (self.lr*np.mean(d_w2))
        weights[2][0] -= (self.lr*np.mean(d_w3))

        return weights

    def cost_function(self, x_featureset, y_targets, weights):
        """
        x_featureset - (160,3)
        y_targets - (160,1)
        predictions - (160,1)
        weights - (3,1)
        """

        total_observation = len(y_targets)
        predictions = self.predict(x_featureset, weights)
        sq_error = (y_targets-predictions)**2
        return 1.0/(2*total_observation) * sq_error.sum()

    def normalize(self, x_featureset):
        """
        x_featureset - (160,3)
        x_featureset.T - (3,160)
        """
        for features in x_featureset.T:
            fmean = np.mean(features)
            frange = np.amax(features) - np.amin(features)

            #vector subtraction
            features -= fmean
            #vector division
            features /= frange

        return x_featureset

    def train(self, x, y):
        cost_history = []
        #nomalize independent variables
        x = self.normalize(x)
        for i in range(self.n_iters):
            self.weights = self.update_param(x, y, self.weights)
            cost = self.cost_function(x,y, self.weights)
            cost_history.append(cost)
            #log process
            if i % 10 == 0:
                print("cost: {}".format(cost))

    def predict(self, x_featureset, weights):
        """
        featureset - (160,3)
        weights - (3,1)
        predictions - (160,1)
        """
        y_predicted = np.dot(x_featureset, weights)
        return y_predicted

#generating sample data using sklearn
def generate_data():
    x, y = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=3, noise=20, random_state=4)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)
    return (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)

#create model instance
model = LinearRegression()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = generate_data()

#fit the data
model.train(x_train, y_train)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest following Code which performs Multivariate Regression of the Model

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn import datasets

class LinearRegression:
    def __init__(self, learning_rate=0.0001, n_iters=1000):
        self.lr = learning_rate
        self.n_iters = n_iters
        #since we have three independent variable, we initialize 4 weights with zeros
        self.weights = np.array([[0.0],[0.0],[0.0],[0.0]])

    def update_param(self, x_featureset, y_targets, weights):
        """
        x_featureset - (160,3)
        y_targets - (160,1)
        predictions - (160,1)
        weights - (4,1)
        """
        predictions = self.predict(x_featureset, weights)

        #extract the features
        x1 = x_featureset[:,0]
        x2 = x_featureset[:,1]
        x3 = x_featureset[:,2]

        #calculate partial derivatives
        d_w0 = - (y_targets - predictions)
        d_w1 = -x1*(y_targets - predictions)
        d_w2 = -x2*(y_targets - predictions)
        d_w3 = -x3*(y_targets - predictions)

        #multiply derivative by learning rate and subtract from our weights
        weights[0][0] -= (self.lr * np.mean(d_w0))
        weights[1][0] -= (self.lr * np.mean(d_w1))
        weights[2][0] -= (self.lr *np.mean(d_w2))
        weights[3][0] -= (self.lr*np.mean(d_w3))

        return weights

    def cost_function(self, x_featureset, y_targets, weights):
        """
        x_featureset - (160,3)
        y_targets - (160,1)
        predictions - (160,1)
        weights - (4,1)
        """

        total_observation = len(y_targets)
        predictions = self.predict(x_featureset, weights)
        sq_error = (y_targets-predictions)**2
        return 1.0/(2*total_observation) * sq_error.sum()

    def normalize(self, x_featureset):
        """
        x_featureset - (160,3)
        x_featureset.T - (3,160)
        """
        for features in x_featureset.T:
            fmean = np.mean(features)
            frange = np.amax(features) - np.amin(features)

            #vector subtraction
            features -= fmean
            #vector division
            features /= frange

        return x_featureset

    def train(self, x, y):
        cost_history = []
        #nomalize independent variables
        x = self.normalize(x)
        for i in range(self.n_iters):
            self.weights = self.update_param(x, y, self.weights)
            cost = self.cost_function(x,y, self.weights)
            cost_history.append(cost)
            #log process
            if i % 10 == 0:
                print("cost: {}".format(cost))

    def predict(self, x_featureset, weights):
        """
        featureset - (160,3)
        weights - (4,1)
        predictions - (160,1)
        """
        # Y = W0 + W1* X1 + W2 * X2 + W3 * X3 
        y_predicted = weights[0,:]+np.dot(x_featureset, weights[1:,:])
        return y_predicted

#generating sample data using sklearn
def generate_data():
    x, y = datasets.make_regression(n_samples=200, n_features=3, noise=20, random_state=4)
    x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.2, random_state=1234)
    return (x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test)

#create model instance
model = LinearRegression()
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = generate_data()

#fit the data
model.train(x_train, y_train)
```

Output:

```
cost: 980808.7969914433
cost: 980757.9150537294
cost: 980707.1372473323
cost: 980656.4633691043
cost: 980605.8932163038
cost: 980555.4265865949
cost: 980505.0632780452
cost: 980454.8030891262
cost: 980404.6458187121
cost: 980354.5912660785
cost: 980304.6392309029
cost: 980254.7895132622
cost: 980205.0419136335
cost: 980155.3962328921
cost: 980105.8522723109
cost: 980056.4098335612
cost: 980007.0687187086
cost: 979957.8287302161
cost: 979908.6896709399
cost: 979859.6513441313
cost: 979810.7135534338
cost: 979761.8761028836
cost: 979713.138796909
cost: 979664.5014403281
cost: 979615.9638383496
cost: 979567.5257965708
cost: 979519.1871209786
cost: 979470.9476179467
cost: 979422.8070942352
cost: 979374.7653569917
cost: 979326.8222137484
cost: 979278.9774724214
cost: 979231.2309413117
cost: 979183.5824291029
cost: 979136.031744861
cost: 979088.578698033
cost: 979041.2230984472
cost: 978993.9647563117
cost: 978946.8034822136
cost: 978899.7390871193
cost: 978852.7713823715
cost: 978805.9001796913
cost: 978759.1252911751
cost: 978712.4465292948
cost: 978665.8637068978
cost: 978619.3766372039
cost: 978572.9851338081
cost: 978526.689010676
cost: 978480.4880821462
cost: 978434.3821629275
cost: 978388.3710680995
cost: 978342.4546131112
cost: 978296.6326137795
cost: 978250.9048862904
cost: 978205.271247197
cost: 978159.7315134181
cost: 978114.2855022394
cost: 978068.9330313113
cost: 978023.6739186477
cost: 977978.5079826281
cost: 977933.4350419926
cost: 977888.4549158453
cost: 977843.5674236503
cost: 977798.7723852337
cost: 977754.0696207809
cost: 977709.4589508367
cost: 977664.9401963042
cost: 977620.5131784454
cost: 977576.177718878
cost: 977531.9336395771
cost: 977487.7807628732
cost: 977443.7189114518
cost: 977399.7479083528
cost: 977355.8675769694
cost: 977312.0777410483
cost: 977268.3782246873
cost: 977224.7688523371
cost: 977181.2494487979
cost: 977137.8198392204
cost: 977094.4798491052
cost: 977051.2293043006
cost: 977008.0680310033
cost: 976964.9958557582
cost: 976922.0126054548
cost: 976879.1181073303
cost: 976836.3121889662
cost: 976793.5946782889
cost: 976750.9654035685
cost: 976708.4241934177
cost: 976665.9708767924
cost: 976623.6052829901
cost: 976581.3272416494
cost: 976539.1365827485
cost: 976497.0331366067
cost: 976455.0167338816
cost: 976413.0872055686
cost: 976371.2443830017
cost: 976329.488097852
cost: 976287.8181821259
cost: 976246.2344681664
```

Update:

Testing with `lr=0.001` because above Learning Rate was too large and iterations to `100000`. I found that the model converges around following values of the cost.

```
cost: 959301.8925571552
cost: 959298.6367338672
cost: 959296.3380453996
cost: 959294.9824055596
cost: 959294.5560072181
cost: 959295.0453167808
cost: 959296.4370687702
cost: 959298.7182605114
cost: 959301.8761469286
```

Answer (score 0):

First off there is expression (syntax) error in your code.

```
d_w1 = -x1*(y_targets - predictions)
d_w2 = -x2*(y_targets - predictions)
d_w3 = -x2*(y_targets - predictions)
```

Should be:

```
d_w1 = -x1*(y_targets - predictions)
d_w2 = -x2*(y_targets - predictions)
d_w3 = -x3*(y_targets - predictions)
```

Now this does causes the Cost to decreases a bit though. But I do not think this has converged to Global Optimum. Will review and update if I can optimize it further.
Output:

```
cost: 980813.8909325758
cost: 980813.8924092407
cost: 980813.8963470139
cost: 980813.9027458953
cost: 980813.9116058851
cost: 980813.9229269831
cost: 980813.9367091894
cost: 980813.952952504
cost: 980813.9716569266
cost: 980813.9928224577
cost: 980814.0164490971
cost: 980814.0425368445
cost: 980814.0710857003
cost: 980814.1020956644
cost: 980814.1355667366
cost: 980814.171498917
cost: 980814.2098922059
cost: 980814.250746603
cost: 980814.2940621084
cost: 980814.3398387218
cost: 980814.3880764437
cost: 980814.4387752739
cost: 980814.4919352122
cost: 980814.5475562587
cost: 980814.6056384137
cost: 980814.6661816769
cost: 980814.729186048
cost: 980814.7946515278
cost: 980814.8625781157
cost: 980814.9329658119
cost: 980815.0058146162
cost: 980815.0811245289
cost: 980815.1588955498
cost: 980815.239127679
cost: 980815.3218209165
cost: 980815.4069752623
cost: 980815.4945907161
cost: 980815.5846672785
cost: 980815.6772049487
cost: 980815.7722037275
cost: 980815.8696636144
cost: 980815.9695846096
cost: 980816.0719667133
cost: 980816.1768099251
cost: 980816.284114245
cost: 980816.3938796733
cost: 980816.5061062098
cost: 980816.6207938545
cost: 980816.7379426076
cost: 980816.8575524688
cost: 980816.9796234384
cost: 980817.1041555163
cost: 980817.2311487021
cost: 980817.3606029968
cost: 980817.4925183991
cost: 980817.6268949099
cost: 980817.7637325292
cost: 980817.9030312565
cost: 980818.0447910922
cost: 980818.1890120357
cost: 980818.3356940881
cost: 980818.4848372485
cost: 980818.6364415172
cost: 980818.7905068938
cost: 980818.9470333789
cost: 980819.1060209726
cost: 980819.267469674
cost: 980819.431379484
cost: 980819.5977504023
cost: 980819.7665824285
cost: 980819.9378755633
cost: 980820.1116298061
cost: 980820.2878451576
cost: 980820.4665216169
cost: 980820.6476591846
cost: 980820.8312578606
cost: 980821.0173176448
cost: 980821.2058385374
cost: 980821.3968205382
cost: 980821.5902636473
cost: 980821.7861678643
cost: 980821.9845331898
cost: 980822.1853596235
cost: 980822.3886471657
cost: 980822.594395816
cost: 980822.8026055746
cost: 980823.0132764415
cost: 980823.2264084164
cost: 980823.4420014997
cost: 980823.6600556913
cost: 980823.880570991
cost: 980824.1035473992
cost: 980824.3289849155
cost: 980824.55688354
cost: 980824.787243273
cost: 980825.0200641142
cost: 980825.2553460634
cost: 980825.4930891211
cost: 980825.733293287
cost: 980825.9759585612
```

Comment: Thank you for your input. why is it that the cost comes to be that high? it is because of normalization issue?

Comment: Probably. When the weights are updated during execution time, it seems okay. Since this is Linear regression model and you are optimizing using Minimization of Least Squares the high-cost can be because the Best Fit is underfitting (or not generalizing) the training data well. Will have to study the dataset first to say anything.

Comment: That makes sense. Also, why do we need the weight (W0) in the equation. Can you please explain how is that helping the model ?

Comment: W0 is the intercept or Bias that is added into the model so that it represents a linear equation. `Y=MX+C` in Matrix Form, which is essentially what Linear Regression is.